# colorbar showing two sets of labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have an imshow plot in Python with a colorbar.

I wanted to position my colorbar in a certain place and have the orientation horizontal, and so I have the following:

```
cbaxes0 = fig.add_axes([0.65, 0.89, 0.25, 0.01])
cb0 = plt.colorbar(cax = cbaxes0,orientation="horizontal")
cb0.update_ticks()
plt.colorbar()
```

It almost works, but as well having ticks and labels on the bottom of the bar, they are squashed on the right hand side as well, but I can't figure out why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `set_ticks()` on the colorbar figure object itself. This overwrites `set_xticklabels()` on any subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import randn

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)
cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[-1, 0, 1], orientation='horizontal')
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(['Low', 'Medium', 'High'])# horizontal colorbar
cbar.set_ticks([0.65, 0.89, 0.25, 0.01])
cbar.update_ticks()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample with colorbar on different axes.

The problem you facing is not clear to me. If possible could you include an image, showing the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import randn

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)
im = ax1.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax1.set_title('Gaussian noise with vertical colorbar')

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.28, 0.39, 0.45, 0.01])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax2, ticks=[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1], orientation='horizontal')
cbar.ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
cbar.ax.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]